# Integrating Azure Cognitive services with Robotic Process Automation

Tags: uipath, azure-cognitive-services, blueprism, rpa, automationanywhere

I have seen Microsoft Cognitive services such as text analytics and some other services.
Here I have gone through RPA and now I need to integrate RPA with any kind of Cognitive services, just for a demo purpose.
Do we have any reference for that to understand much about it ?

If I need to use Azure cognitive services with RPA tools, which one will be the best among UiPath,Automation Anywhere and BluePrism ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automation anywhere has support for making SOAP as well as REST Service call 
You can call REST Service to MS Cognitive services and receive data

in addition to this you can also write your customized code in C# and with feature of Metabot in Automation Anywhere you can invoke your library function as well.

In short Automation Anywhere has various options through which you can integrate make call to MS cognitive service depending upon your requirement

I've built myself wrapper API in ASP.net WebAPI to consume Cognitive API of Microsoft it all matter that you can call this REST Service using Automation Anywhere .
[image: See this Image for REST Command in Automation Anywhere]

Answer (score 1):

Blue Prism has full support of .net coding, so anything that can be done with C# or VB.net, can also be done with it. i haven't had a chance to combine these technologies, but as far as I know, it should be pretty straightforward.